# Can't increase contract balance. Bug?

Tags: contract-debugging

New to Ethereum.  Started working with a simple sample contract.  It's working correctly except for the fact that I simply cannot seem to increase its balance.  Any thoughts?

```
contract Faucet {
    address owner;
    uint256 sendAmount;

    function Faucet() {
        owner = msg.sender;
        sendAmount = 1000000000000000000;
    }

    function getBalance() returns (uint) {
         return this.balance;
    }

    function getWei() returns (bool) {
        return msg.sender.send(sendAmount);
    }

    function sendWei(address toWhom) returns (bool) {
        return toWhom.send(sendAmount);
    }

    function getSendAmount() returns (uint256) {
        return sendAmount;
    }

    function killMe() returns (bool) {
        if (msg.sender == owner) {
            suicide(owner);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Then, using Geth :

```
eth.getBalance(faucetAddress)
1000000000000000000
```

Next...

```
eth.sendTransaction({from:eth.coinbase, to:faucetAddress, amount:1000000000000000000})
```

Block is mined, then:

```
eth.getBalance(faucetAddress)
1000000000000000000
```

No increase.

Here's my transaction receipt.  Many thanks in advance.

```
{
 blockHash: "0x6dacad47ad5f6a4e8dbb38a70bbe77b1d2ef019df396642c0490afc7e5ad2c8c",
 blockNumber: 1526,
 contractAddress: null,
 cumulativeGasUsed: 90000,
 from: "0x245d5fef6bf170a0fc6b464f033bff2aea020dbd",
 gasUsed: 90000,
 logs: [],
 root: "9da791d719134c34bdad70c6cfcc424a1daa1a1573a6319f475a61b7d2728b80",
 to: "0xeff6f295823648420cd1e6707caf99340c2343d0",
 transactionHash: "0xbc6c596afe9e05eb496d85472ade592fbb179fd7b4e0a619cba84bd8930da35b",
 transactionIndex: 0
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of Solidity 0.4, contracts must explicitly allow themselves to receive ETH by defining a fallback function with the `payable` modifier. It would look like this in your case:

```
function() payable {}
```

Just put that at the bottom of your contract and you should be good to go. Note that any function that wants to accept ETH must now use the `payable` modifier.

This is the relevant release note

> Contracts that want to receive Ether with a plain "send" have to implement a fallback function with the payable modifier. Contracts now throw if no payable fallback function is defined and no function matches the signature.

See all breaking changes and release notes: https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/releases/tag/v0.4.0